# The associationrefers to the owning side field e which is not defined as association, but as field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I'm making a blog project. So I have an article Class and a Commentaire Blog class.

But I'm having an error when I want to link boths :

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Article' mapping
>   is invalid:
>   * The association AppBundle\Entity\Article#commentaires refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog#message which is
>   not defined as association, but as field.
>   * The association AppBundle\Entity\Article#commentaires refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog#message which does
>   not exist.
>
> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog'
>   mapping is invalid:
>   * The mappings AppBundle\Entity\Commentaire_blog#article and AppBundle\Entity\Article#commentaires are inconsistent with each
>   other.

I'm a bit lost...

Here are my both Class :

```
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
 class Article
 {
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Titre", type="text")
 */
private $titre;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="article", type="text")
 */
private $article;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_article", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateArticle;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire_blog", mappedBy="messa")
 */
private $commentaires;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->commentaires = new ArrayCollection();

}

/**
 * @return Collection|Commentaire_blog[]
 */
public function getCommentaires()
{
    return $this->commentaires;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titre
 *
 * @param string $titre
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function setTitre($titre)
{
    $this->titre = $titre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titre
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitre()
{
    return $this->titre;
}

/**
 * Set article
 *
 * @param string $article
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function setArticle($article)
{
    $this->article = $article;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get article
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getArticle()
{
    return $this->article;
}

/**
 * Set dateArticle
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateArticle
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function setDateArticle($dateArticle)
{
    $this->dateArticle = $dateArticle;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateArticle
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateArticle()
{
    return $this->dateArticle;
}
```

And The second :

```
* Commentaire_blog
*
* @ORM\Table(name="commentaire_blog")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository      \Commentaire_blogRepository")
*/
class Commentaire_blog
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="usernamne", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $usernamne;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_visible", type="boolean")
 */
private $isVisible;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getArticle()
{
    return $this->article;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $article
 */
public function setArticle($article)
{
    $this->article = $article;
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="commentaires")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $article;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set usernamne
 *
 * @param string $usernamne
 *
 * @return Commentaire_blog
 */
public function setUsernamne($usernamne)
{
    $this->usernamne = $usernamne;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get usernamne
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsernamne()
{
    return $this->usernamne;
}

/**
 * Set message
 *
 * @param string $message
 *
 * @return Commentaire_blog
 */
public function setMessage($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get message
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMessage()
{
    return $this->message;
}

/**
 * Set isVisible
 *
 * @param boolean $isVisible
 *
 * @return Commentaire_blog
 */
public function setIsVisible($isVisible)
{
    $this->isVisible = $isVisible;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isVisible
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getIsVisible()
{
    return $this->isVisible;
}

}
```

Any Idea how to make the link correct...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Class Article:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire_blog", mappedBy="article")
 */
private $commentaires;
```

Class commentaire_blog:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="commentaires")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $article;
```

Also, consider converting the getCommentaires result to Array:

```
public function getCommentaires()
{
    return $this->commentaires->toArray();
}
```

To understand more about the owning and inverse side of each relation try reading this: [Associations: Owning and Inverse Side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/unitofwork-associations.html).